# How do I import a JavaScript module in TypeScript and cast to TypeScript namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet, typescript-typings, monkeypatching

I have a JS file that monkey patches some functionality onto 3rd party packages:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.pm';
import 'leaflet-textpath';

...
// do monkeypatching with all 3 packages.
// Only leaflet and leaflet.pm have typedef packages.
...

export default L;
```

`L` (leaflet) has a `@types` package that includes all the types.

```
export as namespace L;

...
// export all type defs
...
```

At this point in time I don't want to convert the monkeypatch JS file to TS. I can deal with not having typechecking for the monkeypatched functionality.

Given this I am trying to import `monkeypatch.js` as the `L` namespace so I can use it with at least `L` types.

I've tried various things such as the following but haven't had any luck:

```
import MonkeyPatch from 'monkey-patch';

const TS = MonkeyPatch as L;
```

This doesn't work due to not being able to use a namespace `L` as a type.

How can I import the monkeypatch JS file as the `L` namespace so I have `L` typechecking?